# Error 2908 when installing assemblies into GAC

Tags: assemblies, windows-installer, gac, installshield

---

Hi, I'm receiving 2908 (0x80131047: The given assembly name or code-base is invalid) error when running my MSI package.

The problem occures when the MSI tries to deploy a component with .NET assembly into a GAC. NOTE: only assemblies with dependencies fail. The MSI is created with IS 2010.

I am able to deploy the assembly manually with GACUTIL. I verified .NET Framework (all versions upto 3,5)is installed. I verified assembly properties are identical with MsiAssemblyName table properties.

However, somehow I had made the installation working fine before. But when the product was moved to Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.0 I started facing the problem.

Do you guys have any thought on this. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/05/06/2457576.aspx

Comment: Does your assembly name contain an apostrophe?  Remove it.

Comment: The name of the assembly doesn't have any special symbols. What's more, I even tried to remane it to the simplest name I could think of. No luck.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've covered the basics....   CLR version installed,  Files key files of own components, destdir set to GAC,  files are strong named and deployable via GACUTIL.

Hmmm.  Nothing is jumping out at me.   What does the MSI log say when it comes time to call MsiPublishAssemblies?   Do these files have companion resources ( that need to belong to the same component. )

Comment: All information I can capture from the log is - "0x80131047: The given assembly name or code-base is invalid". I've being browsing the inet for this error code but can't find anything new worth to try.

The good thing is that I found a workaround! I can install the assembly when I do that within brand new component. The components are identical! I keep searching the difference but no results so far. The workaround might ne good enough but I'm afraid to get the same problem when come closer to delivery date. :))

Thanks much !